# Need help regarding setting up an airdrop

Tags: erc-721, erc-1155

I’ve been looking for information that could help me with the following but haven’t had much luck.

I’m trying to find a a way that I can airdrop erc721 and erc1155 tokens to token holders of a specific erc-1155 NFT. Essentially holders would be added to a discord and I want to be able to airdrop to random holders of the nft from the list. If anyone can help me find a way to do this I would be much appreciative.
Thanks

Comment: "Random" is an important word. Please clarify. I'm currently working on this for another client where it's random without trust from for the project owner~~and this has some tradeoffs.

Comment: I mean random in a way say I have a list of 100 eth addresses (the token holders) and one nft to give away.. I want that to be sent to s completely random address from that list. Thanks

Comment: If I can buy this off you I’m interested… what platform would it be ran from?

Comment: I have it on Ethereum Mainnet / latest Solidity / Hardhat tests. I'm at https://phor.net